# FloatThead Table With a collapsible div above it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slidetoggle

I have a table that contains a large amount of data. I needed a way to lock the table header at the top of the page when scrolling. I incorporated FloatThead jquery class within the page using a window scroll and a fixed position, it works great.

However, I have a collapsible div that has a height of 600px and the table is right below this. The page loads with the div collapsed. When I click the button to toggle the div the table header stays in the middle of the div, at it's original position, until a mouse wheel event happens then the header moves to the beginning of the table. The same thing happens when I click to collapse the div.

Any help fixing this would be great.

jQuery

```
<script>
    fl(document).ready(function(){
        fl(".sticky-header").floatThead({position: 'fixed'});
    });

    o(function(){
        o('.dashLegend').click(function(){
            o(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle("slow");
            var text = document.getElementById("dash").innerHTML;
                if(text == "Click to Hide Statistics Table") {
                    document.getElementById("dash").innerHTML = "Click to Show Statistics Table";
                } else if(text =="Click to Show Statistics Table") {
                    document.getElementById("dash").innerHTML = "Click to Hide Statistics Table";
                }
        });
   });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<fieldset>
   <legend class="dashLegend" style="color:#0000EE;" id="dash">Click to Show Statistics Table</legend> 
     <div class="content" style="height:600px;">content</div>
</fieldset>

<table class="table sticky-header move" id="tableBorder" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="alignBottom" >
           <th class="noBottomBorder alignBottom" id="nameTh" onClick="changeNameArrow()" style="width: 20%;"><img id="nameArrow" src="images/UpAndDown1.png" >Name</img></th>
           <th class="noBottomBorder">Grade When Administered</th>
           <th class="noBottomBorder">Gender</th>
           <th class="noBottomBorder">Ethnicity</th>
           <th class="noBottomBorder alignBottom" id="elaTh" onClick="changeELAArrow()"><img id="ELAArrow" src="images/UpAndDown1.png" />PASS ELA Scale Score</th>
           <th class="noBottomBorder">PASS ELA</th>
       </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>content</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for this that is included in the floatthead class that I missed before. This allows for the DOM to be manipulated about the table and the header to move appropriately.

```
position: 'absolute'
```

instead of

```
position: 'fixed'
```

Comment: Made no difference for my application

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue as you described and experimented with changing the `position` value and also setting `autoReflow` to true, but neither rectified the issue of another element on the page changing, causing the position of the floating header to change on the page.

I was required to come up with a fix that allowed me to preserve the animation of the bootstrap collapsible panel above the panel containing the floating header.

My solution was as follows:

- When one of the disrupting panels is expanded or collapsed, hide the floating header by setting opacity to zero, avoiding use of `display: none` so to preserve positioning/internal workings of the floatThead floating header. This prevents ugly display while the DOM objects are still in transition, i.e. expanding/collapsing, but keeps the overall layout intact.
- Once the transitions are complete, manually trigger a [reflow event](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/), i.e. `$table.trigger('reflow');` on my main dashboard table to force the plugin to re-align the floated header.
- The reflow event seemed to take about 0.1 or 0.2 seconds to execute on my page, so wrapped in a brief `setTimeout`, quickly fade the floating header back in.

Worked a charm for me. See the javascript I wrote to achieve this below:

---

```
// when one of the panels above the dashboard is expanded or collapsed,
// set the floating header opacity to zero
$('#disruptivePanels .collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.kv-thead-float').css('opacity', 0);
});

// trigger position reflow on main dashboard floating header, then fade back into view
$('#disruptivePanels .collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#dashboardMain table').trigger('reflow');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.kv-thead-float').fadeTo(200, 1);
    }, 400);
});
```